# ui-sref or $state.go not working on first directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I have an ng-repeat on a directive where I'm passing in 3 pieces of information. The directive has a button where I pass that information on to another view using params as such:

```
ui-sref='profiles.show({userId:profile._id, index:index, list:list})
```

The problem I have is that the buttons for all of the cards (the cards are the directives) worked properly, except for the one at index 0. The button won't perform a `ui-sref` or a `$state.go`. I tried having it with an ng-click and console logging all the params and the console log works displaying the correct data, but the `$state.go` with the params is not triggering.

```
$state.go('profiles.show', {userId: profile._id, index: index, list: list})
```

Also, if I remove the index and the list from the params, the ui-sref or $state.go for the first element works again, but in the next view I don't get the necessary information anymore.

Here is the state config for `profiles.show`

```
.state('profiles.show', {url: '/{userId}', params: { index: null, list: null }, templateUrl:'/views/profiles/show/show.html', controller: 'ProfilesShowController'})
```

And here is the ng-repeat (I'm using Jade):

```
.text-capitalize(al-card, ng-repeat='profile in profiles | filter:searchBar track by $index', profile='profile', index='$index', list='profiles')
```

This is the button with the `ng-click`

```
button.btn.btn-default(ng-click='goToProfile(profile, index, list)') Learn More
```

And the $scope function:

```
$scope.goToProfile = function(profile, index, list) {
  console.log(profile);
  console.log(index);
  console.log(list);
  $state.go('profiles.show', {userId: profile._id, index: index, list: list});
};
```

Any help with this?

Comment: Can you post the state config for profiles.show please?

Comment: also your ng-repeat string

Comment: I added the state config @KevinF

Comment: Also added the ng-repeat string @Ronnie

Comment: Can you post the part of the ng-repeat where you are calling profiles.show? I'm wondering if its taking 0 as a falsy value since you're defaulting it to null and treating the two as the same thing

Comment: Added it to the question @KevinF

Comment: Your code looks pretty good, but I've had weird issues with ui-router parameters before. Its just hard to debug without seeing what is happening. What happens when index is 0? Does it make it to ProfileShowController, or does it redirect to index, or does it just do nothing? And if the index is not 0 then everything works 100%?

Comment: @KevinF when index is 0 it just does nothing, but starting at index 1 everything is fine. I even thought it was the item being passed, but even when I filter and get a new item for index 0 it still doesn't work. Thanks btw!

Answer (score 1):

The problem (as @KevinF mentioned) was that index 0 was being taken as a falsy value, to solve it I just modified this line:

```
.text-capitalize(al-card, ng-repeat='profile in profiles | filter:searchBar track by $index', profile='profile', index='$index', list='profiles')
```

to:

```
.text-capitalize(al-card, ng-repeat='profile in profiles | filter:searchBar track by $index', profile='profile', index='$index.toString()', list='profiles')
```

and in the directive I just reassign it to itself with `parseInt($index)`

Answer (score 0):

I made a plunkr here, it seems to work with index 0, so I'm not sure if the issue is the index. Do you see anything different in mine other than the filtering? I think the filtering might be part of the issue

http://plnkr.co/edit/lhU8A3rhUR0JLw5KCNQM

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="Test">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@~1.4.0-rc.2" data-semver="1.4.0-rc.2" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.2/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="ui-router@*" data-semver="0.2.15" src="//rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-router/0.2.15/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ui-view></div>
  </body>

</html>
-------------------------------------------
<div ng-controller="SelectProfile">
  <button ng-repeat="profile in profiles track by $index" 
  ui-sref="profile({userId: profile.userId, index: $index})">
    {{ profile.userId }}
  </button>
</div>
----------------------------------------------
<div ng-controller="Profile">
  {{ profile.userId }}
  <br>
  {{ profile.index }}
</div>

<a ui-sref="home">home</a>
-----------------------------------------------
(function(){
  angular.module('Test', ['ui.router']);

  angular.module('Test')
    .run(function($rootScope, $state, $stateParams){
      $rootScope.$state = $state;
      $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
    });

  angular.module('Test')
    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

      $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: 'home.html'
            })
            .state('profile', {
              url: '/:userId',
              params: {
                index: null,
                list: null
              },
              templateUrl: 'profile.html'
            });
    });

  angular.module('Test')
    .controller('SelectProfile', function($scope){
      $scope.profiles = [
        {userId: 1},
        {userId: 2},
        {userId: 3}
      ];
    });

  angular.module('Test')
    .controller('Profile', function($scope, $rootScope){
      $scope.profile = {
        userId: $rootScope.$stateParams.userId,
        index: $rootScope.$stateParams.index
      };
    });
})();
```

Comment: The problem was the index 0 as a number, all I had to do was parse it into a string and pass it like that: `{... index: $index.toString(), ...}` and that made it work!